# Continuity of the multiplication map $f\mapsto x^2 f(x)$ between normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Let $F:C[0,2]\to C[0,2]$ be the map defined by $(F(f))(x)=x^2f(x)$. Show that $F$ is continuous as a function from $(C[0,2],\|\cdot\|_{\sup})$ to $(C[0,2],\|\cdot\|_{2})$.

I read this solution:

> Let $f\in C[0,2]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=\epsilon/(4\sqrt{2})$. If $\|g-f\|_{\sup}<\delta$ we have 
>   $$
> \|F(g)-F(f)\|_2 = \left(\int_0^2 x^4(f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx\right)^{1/2} \le 2^2\sqrt{2}\|g-f\|_\sup<4\sqrt{2}\delta=\epsilon
> $$

I'm confused how the marker got the inequality from $$\left(\int_0^2 x^4(f(x)-g(x))^2 \ dx \right)^{1/2} \leq 2^2 \sqrt{2} ||g-f||_{sup}$$

Could someone please explain this step for me, and how they got the motivation to set $\delta = \epsilon/(4\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: The $\delta=\varepsilon/(4 \sqrt{2})$ comes by doing the first part of the proof and seeing that you get $\| F(g) - F(f) \|_2 \leq 4 \sqrt{2} \| g - f \|_\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, $\delta$ was chosen *after* the estimate arrived at $\le 4\sqrt2 \delta$. For the estimate, note that $(f(x) - g(x))^2 \le \|g-f\|_\text{sup}^2$, thus
$$\left(\int_0^2 x^4 (f(x)-g(x))^2 \ \mathrm dx \right)^{\frac12} \le \left( \|g-f\|_\text{sup}^2 \int_0^2 x^4 \ \mathrm dx\right)^{\frac12} = \sqrt{\frac{2^5}5} \|g-f\|_\text{sup}$$
So the constant could even be improved to $\sqrt{\frac{2^5}5} = 2^2 \sqrt{\frac25} < 2^2 \sqrt2$.

Comment: I'm unsure how you managed to the $(f(x) - g(x))^2$ out of the integral, could you explain

Comment: @user212076 We used the point-wise estimate $(f(x)-g(x))^2 \le \|g-f\|_\text{sup}^2$. The latter is a constant so we can pull it out of the integral.

Comment: ah ok, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f,g\geq0$ then we certainly have
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\ dx\leq(b-a)\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\max_{x\in[a,b]}g(x).$$
If you're unsure of why, look at the graph. In this case, $x^4,(f(x)-g(x))^2\geq0$ and so
$$\int_0^2x^4(f(x)-g(x))^2\ dx\leq2\cdot2^4\|f-g\|_\sup$$
from which your inequality follows by taking square roots. Usually in this kind of proof the choice of $\delta$ seems rather opaque until you work backwards. Choose $\delta>0$ and you will end up with
$$2^2\sqrt2\|f-g\|_\sup\leq4\sqrt2\delta$$
and we want $4\sqrt2\delta\le\epsilon$, so $\delta=\frac\epsilon{4\sqrt{2}}$ is the natural choice.

Comment: Intersting that a more basic estimate, $(f(x)-g(x))^2 \le \|f-g\|_\infty^2$ yields a better factor...

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising. You have explicitly solved $\int_0^2x^4\ dx$ whereas I (and the marker) have just found a crude upper bound. It stands to reason that your constant is sharper.

Comment: The general method of pointwise estimate via $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ also has more power in the sense that it can prove bounds for infinite integrals as well (say $\int_{\mathbb R} \sin x e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \ \mathrm dx$ for instance). I wonder why the marker chose this estimate, it seems unnatural to me in this context...

Comment: Yeah, of course. I just chose to do it the way the marker did so the OP could see what they were doing.

Comment: I actually thought he had left the $\frac1{\sqrt5}$ out for convenience until I saw your answer^^